# Roll die and return number of 4's Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, dice

I need to write a function to roll a 4-sided die N times and return the number of 4's rolled.  I want to use randperm and a for lop in my Matlab function. So far i have:

```
function [value2] = rollDie( N )

%This function inputs the number of times a 4-sided die is rolled and
%returns the number of times a 2 was rolled.

%   N = the number of times the die was rolled

x = ranperm(4);

v = x(1);

count = 0;

for v = 2

    count = count + 1;
end
```

I'm not sure if this is even correct to begin with, but i also cant figure out how to make the function run through N times based on the input of the number of times rolled.

Comment: Can you find out how many times your loop is running? Do you think it's what it should be?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a random vector or numbers from 1 to 6 using `randi`, or random integer generator. Your code would look like

```
function count = rollDire(N)

% Produce N random rolls of a 6-sided die
rolls = randi(6,1,N);

% Count number of times we encounter the number 4
count = sum(rolls == 4);
```

Comment: what is I have to use randperm in my function? then how would i code it?

Comment: @user3403048 It wounds like you're doing a homework assignment, so I cant do that for you, but I'm sure that you can figure it out pretty easily. You've essentially used it correctly in your example above.

Comment: @user3403048 Just as another hint, `randperm` gives you *one* permutation, but you need to do N of them. So you need to generate N separate permutations and extract their respective first values.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this "return" syntax. It works with count=countFours; return

Comment: @JoeSerrano You're right, that's a mistake on my part.